# What does "to be golfed-out" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "to be golfed-out" mean in the dialog below ?

> - I'm going to the golf tomorrow morning, do you want to join ?
> - Thanks! But I’m pretty **golfed-out**! Just back from Thailand after 2
>     weeks of golf 12 games .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"I’m pretty golfed-out!" means "Right now, I have done enough golfing, so I am too tired (of golfing) to do more."  Person 2 in the quoted dialog is giving an explanation in order to politely refuse Person 1's offer/suggestion.

An expression like "(I am all) X-ed out" can be used as a slangy or informal way of saying "I have done enough of X". This may have arisen by analogy with the expressions "tired out" and "worn out". Other examples:

- "[All Gamed Out](https://www.gamespot.com/forums/xbox-association-1000003/all-gamed-out-27461529/)?" in the sense "tired of games/not feeling like playing games"
- "all photoed out" in the sense "tired of taking photos" : description of [this image](https://www.flickr.com/photos/andrewburrows/3582298707/meta/), body of this [blog post](https://polkadotpearl.wordpress.com/tag/malta/)
- "all oystered out" in the following article: "[The Foodist's 10 Favorite Oyster Bars Across America](https://www.bonappetit.com/columns/the-foodist/article/foodist-oyster-bars)", by Andrew Knowlton

Answer (score 1):

It means that you have played all the golf that you can.

Metaphorically, you don't have anything *golf* left in you still to play.

This meaning of the word comes from one of the senses of the definition of [*out*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> adverb
>
> **3 a** : to the point of depletion, extinction, or exhaustion
> // the food ran *out*
> // turn the light *out*
> // all tuckered *out*

It's the last example in particular that's relevant. The construction of this type of expression is *I'm all [verbed] out*. (Although a noun can also be used.)